# Simple Code Igniter error...silent failure on load->model

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry for the stupid question, but this is driving me crazy...

I have test_framework.php as follows:

```
<?php

  class Test_framework extends CI_Controller{

    function display_test(){
      echo "loading model...";
      $this -> load -> model('test_model');
      echo "model loaded...";
    }
  }
?>
```

and test_model.php as follows:

```
<?php

class Test_model extends Model {

  function get_all(){

    $q = $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM users");

    foreach($q -> result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
  }

} 

?>
```

When I go to my index.php/test_framework/display_test, I see "loading model..." but never "model loaded...", and there are no errors (just a blank white page).  What could be happening wrong here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, your class naming are wrong. Moreover, you have to extend the parent model __construct();

Here you may set an echo to trace the loading of the model:

```
class Test_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct();
  echo 'Model loaded!';  // something like this
}

 function get_all()
{
// your code here
}


}
```

**Edit**: quoting from the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html):

> Class names must have the first letter
>   capitalized with the rest of the name
>   lowercase. Make sure your class
>   extends the base Model class.

The basic prototype (from the manual) is:

```
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

If you want to record the initialization of controllers and models and so on, instead of having them echo something on your page you can enable **logging** in application/config.php :

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;

//  0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
//  1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
//  2 = Debug Messages
//  3 = Informational Messages
//  4 = All Messages
```

Comment: Thanks Damien.  Could you expand on why my class naming is wrong?

Comment: @user cuz that's CIs naming convention, it's on the userguide

Comment: As @atno said, the uppercase is a convention. Extending CI_Model, though, is the right syntax, as the main class is called that way.

Comment: Test_framework and Test_model follow the naming convention, don't they??

Comment: @user507016 yes, they do. Always check the user guide when in doubt, it's the best out there among php frameworks